# Which Models / Controllers are responsible for placing an order from data['cart'] to database?

Tags: opencart

I am creating a custom extension for opencart which allows people to design products such as mugs and tshirts, and it is necessary for me to store information relating to their design in the database.

I am having trouble working out which models and controllers contain the methods responsible for placing an order into the database, and also at what point in the ordering workflow these methods are called, so if anybody knows and can enlighten me, I would be very appreciative, thank you.

*edited as my english is awful, but I do try to remedy the most glaring errors.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controller that it gets called from is `catalog/controller/checkout/confirm.php`
The model is `catalog/model/checkout/order.php` calling the `addOrder()` method which you can find in the controller, called by the following code

```
$this->session->data['order_id'] = $this->model_checkout_order->addOrder($data);
```